# Change setting name in Customizer and keep the data

Tags: theme-development, database, theme-options, theme-customizer

I created a theme while back when I was new to Customizer API and for some weird reasons I named theme settings as:

`$wp_customize->add_setting('thefunk_theme_options[header_color]`

Instead of just `header_color` and saved every setting in an array like `thefunk_theme_options[header_color]`

So I recently found out that it's generating some issues, so I want to save every setting, let's say, `thefunk_theme_options[header_color]` to `header_color` or `thefunk_header_color`.

Now I know how I can change the settings in the Customizer. However, it will affect everyone who is currently using the theme. All the customization will be gone, so does any one know how I can import the data from the old tables and add it to the new tables?

Comment: Are you sure the old data is removed, I don't think so. In that case just try to change the old data's key to the new one.

Comment: @Fleuv I mean data is removed from their site, not database. But how can I change keys of 30-40 some options? Any idea?

Comment: I dont know the solution you are looking for. But I am interested what type of problem you faced. I am using like you did in  my several themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think keeping your mods in an array is a nice solution, but transferring them shouldn't be too difficult. Just loop through the array like this:

```
$all_mods = get_theme_mod('thefunk_theme_options'); // retrieve array
foreach ($all_mods as $key -> $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) set_theme_mod ($key,$value); // set array element as separate mod
    }
```

Since you have to do this only once, when the updated theme is ran first, you may want to insert an extra check upfront and delete the array afterwards.